# Any risk of MySQL connections concurrency?

Tags: php, mysql, concurrency

I'm currently using this code to connect to my DB using Php:

```
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","username","password");
```

this code is inside a `dbConnect.php` file that is included in several other .php files.
Given that everytime someone queries a .php file using `dbConnect` the $con variable is used, is there a risk of concurrency if two or more users query such pages?

If yes, how to avoid it? Using uniqid() to name the connection?

Answer (score 2):

mysql_connect() does not create a persistent connection so the resource will not be shared with other users.

Answer (score 0):

I believe mysql locks connections so I don't think you need to worry about it.